# Modify flutter_quill textStyle

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to modify the 'N' default text style for the flutter quill editor. However, I can't seem to find the option in the DefaultStyles class. Below is my current code:

```
QuillEditor(
       autoFocus: true,
       controller: controller,
       scrollController: scrollController,
       expands: true,
       focusNode: focusNode,
       readOnly: false,
       scrollable: true,
       padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
       customStyles: DefaultStyles(

           h1: DefaultTextBlockStyle(
               GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                   fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, color: darkText),
               Tuple2(16, 0),
               Tuple2(0, 0),
               null),
           h2: DefaultTextBlockStyle(
               GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                   fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, color: darkText),
               Tuple2(16, 0),
               Tuple2(0, 0),
               null),
           h3: DefaultTextBlockStyle(
               GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                   fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, color: darkText),
               Tuple2(16, 0),
               Tuple2(0, 0),
               null),
           strikeThrough: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
               color: darkText, decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
           sizeSmall: GoogleFonts.montserrat(color: darkText),
           italic: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
               color: darkText, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
           bold: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
               color: darkText, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
           underline: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
               color: darkText, decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
           color: darkText),
     ),
```

I've been able to modify the textstyles for h1 to h3 but not the normal (N) option. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the library's implementation, the `DefaultStyles` class has the following vars

```
DefaultStyles({
    this.h1,
    this.h2,
    this.h3,
    this.paragraph,
```

I guess what you're calling "N" is the default style, which should be `paragraph`.
You just have to follow the same logic you had with `h1 h2 h3` and you should be fine

Comment: I don't know how I missed this!, thank you so much!